# Función retorna un válido del arreglo menos

Tags: c

Tengo que pasar datos de libros *(stLibroLista)* desde un **Árbol** hacia un **Arreglo de Listas**.

La función *agregar* sirve para cuando no se encuentre cierto autor en el ADL: se lo agrega y se lo da de *alta*. Funciones auxiliares como *crearNodoLista*, *buscarPosEnArreglo*, etc. funcionan correctamente.

El problema llega al usar *arbolToADL*, que, en caso de que yo cargara 3 autores y 3 libros en el árbol, debería pasar 3 autores y 1 libro por celda (en su respectiva lista), devolviéndome 3 válidos. Pero me retorna 2, y no logro encontrar el error.

```
int agregar(celda A[], char nombrePersona[], int v)
{
    strcpy(A[v].nombrePersona, nombrePersona);
    A[v].listaLibros = inicLista();
    v++;
    return v;
}

int alta(celda A[], char nombrePersona[], stLibroLista libro, int v)
{
    nodoListaLibro*aux = crearNodoLista(libro);
    int pos = buscarPosEnArreglo(A, nombrePersona, v);

    if(pos == -1)
    {
        v = agregar(A,nombrePersona,v);
        pos = v-1;
    }

    A[pos].listaLibros = insertarNodoEnLista(A[pos].listaLibros,aux);
    return v;
}

int arbolToADL (nodoArbol*arbol, celda A[], int dim)
{
    int v = 0;
    stLibroLista datos;
    char nombrePersona[20];

    if(arbol)
    {
        strcpy(nombrePersona, arbol->dato.nombrePersona);
        strcpy(datos.nombreLibro, arbol->dato.nombreLibro);
        strcpy(datos.genero, arbol->dato.genero);
        datos.cantPaginas = arbol->dato.cantPaginas;
        datos.puntaje = arbol->dato.puntaje;

        v = arbolToADL(arbol->izq, A, dim);
        v = arbolToADL(arbol->der, A, dim);
        v = alta(A, nombrePersona, datos, v);
    }

    return v;
}
```

**Código completo:** [aquí](http://paste.debian.net/1223228)

Comment: sin poder ver el código de todas las funciones involucradas es complicado darte una respuesta. Me parece estupendo que digas que las funciones son correctas ... pero eso no me permite saber qué hacen exactamente y cómo eso puede afectar a tu problema

Comment: @eferion dejé un enlace con el código completo, ya pude resolver el problema. Decís que añada comentarios sobre qué hace cada función la próxima? :)

Comment: Entry not found ... enlace incorrecto